# Pandas 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many rows. I wanted to edit a row in daataframe so I do it like this:

```
df = df.loc[int(row)-1] = ['Mohammed', 'Abril', 'Female', 'United States', '32', '15/10/2017', '1562', 'Null']
```

However I just keep getting an error

```
'list' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

I do now know why since this is the right way to edit the row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The output of `print(type(df))` should explain your issue. Seems like your variable `df` is actually a `list` and not a `pandas.DataFrame`

Comment: I did as you said but I get output `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` so I do not know why this is happening

Comment: You have a double assignment, clearly after this line, df is a list.

Comment: good catch- change your code to this: `df.loc[int(row)-1] = ['Mohammed', 'Abril', 'Female', 'United States', '32', '15/10/2017', '1562', 'Null']` and see if that works

Comment: Thank you so much. I still do not know why this occure but after changing it to `df.loc[int(row)-1] = ['Mohammed', 'Abril', 'Female', 'United States', '32', '15/10/2017', '1562', 'Null']` instead of  `df= df.loc[int(row)-1] = ['Mohammed', 'Abril', 'Female', 'United States', '32', '15/10/2017', '1562', 'Null']` it worked. Can you please explain why?

Comment: `a = b = 1` means both `a == 1` and `b == 1` are now true.